# What is the simplest way to find the XML node position of a value?

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to find the `XML` `node` position of `stateInput`

For example, if I select the state "Alabama" from the `datalist` I want my code to return the XML node position of "Alabama" so that related attributes such as "population" can also be retrieved in the results.

What is the simplest solution to this problem?

Note: in this test, I manually set the node position variable = 2. Currently, regardless of the selected state, Node position of state input = 2, State node = California, etc. That's only a correct match if California is selected.

```js
var n = document.getElementById("myInputId");
n.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").click();
    }
});

function testResults() {
    document.getElementById("stateInput").innerHTML = myInputId.value;
}

var parser, xmlDoc, x, i;
var text = 
"<STATE_DATA>" +
"<UNIT>" +
"<STATE>Wisconsin</STATE>"+
"<GDP>232,300,000,000</GDP>"+
"<POPULATION>5,800,000</POPULATION>" +
"</UNIT>" + 
"<UNIT>" +
"<STATE>Alabama</STATE>" +
"<GDP>165,800,000,000</GDP>" +
"<POPULATION>4,900,000</POPULATION>" +
"</UNIT>" +
"<UNIT>" +
"<STATE>California</STATE>" +
"<GDP>2,500,000,000,000</GDP>" +
"<POPULATION>39,600,000</POPULATION>" +
"</UNIT>" +
"<UNIT>" +
"<STATE>Texas</STATE>" +
"<GDP>1,600,000,000,000</GDP>" +
"<POPULATION>28,300,000</POPULATION>" +
"</UNIT>" + 
"<UNIT>" +
"<STATE>Michigan</STATE>" +
"<GDP>382,000,000</GDP>" +
"<POPULATION>10,000,000</POPULATION>" +
"</UNIT>" + 
"</STATE_DATA>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

var a = 2; /*I want: var a = XML node position of stateInput*/
document.getElementById("stateNodePosition").innerHTML = a;

document.getElementById("stateNode").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("STATE")[a].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

document.getElementById("populationNode").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("POPULATION")[a].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

```html
<input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="testResults()">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
<option id="AL">Alabama</option>
<option id="CA">California</option>
<option id="MI">Michigan</option>
<option id="TX">Texas</option>
<option id="WI">Wisconsin</option>
</datalist>

<p>State input: <span id="stateInput"></span></p>
<p>Node position of state input: <span id="stateNodePosition"></span></p>
<p>State node: <span id="stateNode"></span></p>
<p>Population node: <span id="populationNode"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through all `STATE`s and find the one whose `textContent` is the state you want, and then you can access its parent to get to its `UNIT`. The only changes are in `testResults`:

```js
var n = document.getElementById("myInputId");
n.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("myButton").click();
  }
});

function testResults() {
  const { value } = myInputId;
  const foundState = [...xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('STATE')]
    .find(possibleMatch => possibleMatch.textContent === value);
  const unit = foundState.parentElement;
  console.log(unit.innerHTML);
  document.getElementById("stateInput").innerHTML = value + ' has pop ' + unit.children[2].textContent;
}

var parser, xmlDoc, x, i;
var text =
  "<STATE_DATA>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>Wisconsin</STATE>" +
  "<GDP>232,300,000,000</GDP>" +
  "<POPULATION>5,800,000</POPULATION>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>Alabama</STATE>" +
  "<GDP>165,800,000,000</GDP>" +
  "<POPULATION>4,900,000</POPULATION>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>California</STATE>" +
  "<GDP>2,500,000,000,000</GDP>" +
  "<POPULATION>39,600,000</POPULATION>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>Texas</STATE>" +
  "<GDP>1,600,000,000,000</GDP>" +
  "<POPULATION>28,300,000</POPULATION>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>Michigan</STATE>" +
  "<GDP>382,000,000</GDP>" +
  "<POPULATION>10,000,000</POPULATION>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "</STATE_DATA>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");

var a = 2; /*I want: var a = XML node position of stateInput*/
document.getElementById("stateNodePosition").innerHTML = a;

document.getElementById("stateNode").innerHTML =
  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("STATE")[a].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

document.getElementById("populationNode").innerHTML =
  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("POPULATION")[a].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

```html
<input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="testResults()">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
<option id="AL">Alabama</option>
<option id="CA">California</option>
<option id="MI">Michigan</option>
<option id="TX">Texas</option>
<option id="WI">Wisconsin</option>
</datalist>

<p>State input: <span id="stateInput"></span></p>
<p>Node position of state input: <span id="stateNodePosition"></span></p>
<p>State node: <span id="stateNode"></span></p>
<p>Population node: <span id="populationNode"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Then can I use getElementById to place those results in the page instead of in the console?

Comment: Sure, that's what my code does with the `document.getElementById("stateInput").innerHTML = value + ' has pop ' + unit.children[2].textContent;`

Comment: Oh, perfect I'm just seeing that now.

Comment: I'm studying your solution and it's beautiful! I hope your answer will benefit others as well, or is this common knowledge? I couldn't find advice like this anywhere, but I'm just a beginner coder. You made my day!

Comment: `is this common knowledge?` Could be. I do make a good effort to write clean, DRY, functional (as opposed to imperative) code, but I don't know if this sort of thing is common or not. I'm not a professional either. If the answer solved your problem, you might consider marking it as Accepted